# ASP.net: Best way to hold global settings

Tags: asp.net, settings

I need to store settings that update from time to time about my website and was wondering what is the most efficient way to do this.  Note that once these settings are changed, I need them to be accessible even after an IIS reboot, so a simple application variable is not the answer.  I also know I can store application settings in my config file, but as you change them, the actual XML doesn't seem to update, so I would have to re-write the XML behind the scenes each time it changes.

As for writing to an file, such as an INI, my concern arises if as I am writing, another is trying to read.  I have had IO locking errors before doing such a thing.  Also I can do a database storage, but trying to keep database calls low.

Right now I am set on probably having an INI that I write to on change, on application load I pull from that so that I can always access the local variable.  This would make IO issues pretty unlikely since I am only reading once.  Just basically looking for some input on what is likely the most efficient way of doing this.

Thanks in advance,

Anthony F Greco

Comment: Yes, when updated, I would update the global variable, but also write the new value in case IIS restarts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to minimize database calls, I'd say put the values in the database, then cache them in your application. Depending on your needs, maybe expire the cache every 30 minutes, so when you change the DB value, it will be applied in no more than 30 minutes, and you will only make a DB call every 30 minutes (or when needed, like when your app restarts).  Or you can use a SQL Cache Dependency, but I've never done that, so I don't know the pitfalls of that technique.

Comment: Basically seems to be what I was going to do so I will mark this as answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We moved all of our application settings from the web.config to the database as can be seen [HERE.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2009/02/25/Moving-AppSettings-to-a-Database-Table.aspx)

Ours was done to get around the problems with promoting code from Dev to Test to QA to Prod, but it can be used for other reasons.

Ours is cached on application startup and then every 5 minutes it checks to see if a single counter in a table was updated.  If so, it refreshes all of the settings.

Comment: Basically seems to be what I was going to do. I'd mark yours as answered but it matches Joe's just a bit modded, and since his was posted first, marked that.  Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with @Joe Enos
Except that I'd use an xml file or a .ini, as you'd like to limit your db calls.